# When is mt_rand seeded?

Tags: php, random, seeding, random-seed

At what moment is the seed for `mt_rand` selected? According to [several](https://phpsecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Insufficient-Entropy-For-Random-Values.html) [sources](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-12/Briefings/Argyros/BH_US_12_Argyros_PRNG_WP.pdf) 
php should reseed this PRNG in every new process. This works perfectly on my windows machine. On the linux machine however a new seed is used with every request. I checked that the requests are running in the same process (using `getmypid`) and they do. Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you detect when it's reseeded?

Comment: I crack the seed using [php_mt_seed](https://www.openwall.com/php_mt_seed/) and look if I can predict the output of `mt_rand` in future requests.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand that tool, but I'm not sure how it would detect reseeding. You're supposed to give it the first random number after seeding with `mt_srand();`. You're giving it later random numbers as well? Can you post what you're actually doing, what the expected results are, and what you're getting instead?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer. Starting with php7.1 `mt_rand` seeds are not retained. [This](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/e9e860a05be187862a0213f8c6c58aff2293bb22) is the commit for this change.